# Rendering a imported mp4 video within a animation

Tags: rendering, video

I having trouble with creating an animation in Blender which consists of an imported mp4 file and a moving camera. 
The camera just moves from left to right panning an imported .mp4 file. When i preview the animation I can see the .mp4 and its playing but when I render it does not show anything?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My fault. I imported as a plane and it worked. Before I just dragged the .mp4 into Blender, probably just acting as a reference.